# Old Node_modules folder causing build errors

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-cli

Previously I was having issues trying to update vue to the latest version so I renamed my node_modules folder to node_modules_OLD and did an npm install. This created a new node_modules folder and updated everything to the latest version. No problem there, except apparently I should have completely removed the node_modules folder because now when I try to run an npm run build I'm getting the following error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                     14:56:27

This relative module was not found:

* ../../node_modules_OLD/postcss-selector-parser/postcss-selector-parser in ./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/faculty.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 ERROR  Build failed with errors.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

I've since removed the node_modules_OLD folder but I'm still getting the same error where it's looking for node_modules_OLD. I've also removed the node_modules folder completely and ran npm install again, it created the node_modules folder but it's still throwing the same error on npm run build.

Why would it be looking at the node_modules_OLD folder? And how can I get it to stop looking for it? Removing the node_modules_OLD folder doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try delete the file `package-lock.json`, folder node_modules and rerun `npm install`